# firebase query with where getting FirebaseError

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, firebase-admin

I'm using `"firebase": "^9.9.0"`, so web version 9 syntax. I'm trying to get a document by its field value, and im having no luck. I can get all the documents in the collection but every way I try to use `.where` I get errors, this is the main error i get:
`FirebaseError: Expected type 'ba', but it was: a custom Pa object`.

Here is my latest attempt:

```
  const router = useRouter()
  const paletteData = router.query
  const [palette, setPalette] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    const docRef = query(collection(db, 'palettes'), where("slug", "==", "03045e-0077b6-00b4d8-90e0ef-caf0f8"));
    const docSnap = getDoc(docRef)
    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      setPalette(docSnap.data())
      console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
    } else {
      console.log("No such document!");
    }
  }, [router])
```

Another attempt was:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getDoc(doc(db, "palettes"), where("slug", "==", paletteData.palette)).then(docSnap => {
      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    })
  }, [router])
```

Note, `slug` is a field inside of the document in the palette collection.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best solution but after messing around, I got this to work:

```
  const { user } = params
  const userData = []
  const userRef = collection(db, 'users')
  const q = query(userRef, where('uid', '==', user), limit(1))
  const userDoc = await getDocs(q)
  userDoc.forEach((doc) => {
    userData.push(doc.data())
  })

  console.log(userData)
```